# What is the equivalent of uint16_t and uint8_t

Tags: ocaml

What is the equivalent of  uint16_t and uint8_t from C++ in OCaml?
I came across Int64 but I am not sure if its signed or not. Also I am not sure what would be the equivalent of uint8_t from C++ in OCaml?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The types of C++ are meant to match the various sizes of integers of common hardware.

The types of OCaml are at a somewhat higher level (or at least that's how I look at it). So you're not going to find the full range of integer types of C++.

The [basic OCaml language definition](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/language.html) only mentions these integer types:

- `int`: a 31-bit signed value (longer on 64-bit machines; currently the 64-bit implementation defines 63-bit signed values)
- `char`: an 8-bit unsigned value

The [OCaml language extensions document](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html) defines a few more integer types:

- `int32`: a 32-bit signed value
- `int64`: a 64-bit signed value
- `nativeint` : a signed value of the native word size (32 bits on a 32-bit machine; 64 bits on a 64-bit machine)

That's it for integer types!

Here's a session showing values of all these types:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.02.1

# 3;;
- : int = 3
# 'z';;
- : char = 'z'
# 3l;;
- : int32 = 3l
# 3L;;
- : int64 = 3L
# 3n;;
- : nativeint = 3n
#
```

One reason to use narrower integer values is to save space when you have a lot of them. For this case there is the [Bigarray](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Bigarray.html) module, which supports arrays of signed and unsigned values of 8 and 16 bits, plus the integer types listed above.

Answer (score 3):

There is the [uint](https://github.com/andrenth/ocaml-uint/) library that implements different unsigned integer types. If you need the behaviour of a *C*

> uint8_t

just use

> Uint8.t

from this library.

Comment: When attempting to make it - it says its missing setup.data

Comment: just install it via opam!